# HttpClient is modifying my original request to change domains

Tags: c#, .net, dotnet-httpclient

I have some code that is making a Server2Server call using an `HttpClient`.  Here is some quick code

Code to make a request

```
    private HttpRequestMessage GetRequest(Uri uri, NameValueCollection headers)
    {
        var method = HttpMethod.Get;
        var request = new HttpRequestMessage(method, uri);
        foreach (string v in headers)
        {
            var success = request.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation(v, headers[v]);

            if (!success)
            {
                // log something ( no logs are appearing )
            }
        }
        return request;
    }
```

Code to make the request

```
private void AsyncCallUrl(Uri url, NameValueCollection headers)
{
    object result1 = null;
    var handler = new HttpClientHandler() { AllowAutoRedirect = false };
    using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient(handler))
    {
        var request = GetRequest(url, headers);
        using (HttpResponseMessage response = client.SendAsync(request).Result) // when this line is executed the request object's domain is changed to something else
        {
            using (HttpContent content = response.Content)
            {
                result1 = content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
            }
        }
    }
```

I've verified that the `request` object is created appropriately with the proper domain. I've also verified that the network traffic is going to the wrong domain, even the `request` object shows the new bad domain.  What I don't is why this is happening.  I've even set the `AllowAutoRedirect` to `false`

**NOTE:** As a note I notice that if I use `GetAsync` instead of `SendAsync` the domain change doesn't happen.  However this is not an ideal solution as in order to add headers I would need to add them to the `HttpClient` itself and this code lives on an IIS server and I don't want to make a new client for every request

Comment: what is the domain, and do you control the DNS entry / server etc?

Comment: The original domain is a server that my company uses to accept incoming traffic (lets call it prod.company.com), however the the new bad domain is something like (dev.anothercompany.com) where anothercompany is our parent company that just bought us.  Seems to be some IIS config maybe?  I would think that the domain specifics aren't important, just the fact that it's changing

Comment: Does the `NameValueCollection headers` collection happen to contain an entry for `Host`?

Comment: @spender it does, and it has the new bad value, will look at removing this now

Comment: @sedavidw Let me know if it helped... if so I'll write up an answer.

Comment: @spender that appears to have fixed the problem, thanks for the help, if you write it up i'll give ya the check

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, with `SendAsync` the value of the `Host` header of the request is determined by the `uri` parameter... However it is possible to override the `Host` header through the `Headers` property of the request.

It's highly likely that the `NameValueCollection headers` that you are blindly injecting into the request's headers contains an entry for `Host` which is different to that which you supplied in the `Uri`.

---

*As an aside, this behaviour can be useful, if (for instance) you were to discover that the DNS performance of `HttpWebRequest` (the business end of HttpClient on Windows) is sub-standard. I've bypassed .Net/Windows DNS by using a third party library to look up the IP of the host, rewriting the Uri to use the IP address in place of the host name, then setting the `Host` header on the outgoing request back to the original host name.*